# Copy a row from a table and insert a new value in SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with this query, I want to copy some columns and add a new value into the same table but doesn't seem to work right. I can't figure out what is wrong

```
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spInsertCopyDocumentos') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
    @IdArtigo int,
    @IdNovo int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO hDocumentos (IdArtigo) VALUES (@IdNovo)
    SELECT TipoDocumento, NomeDocumento,Dados, Extensao, Observacoes 
    FROM hDocumentos
    WHERE IdArtigo = @IdArtigo
END
```

It says the TipoDocumento is null but it has values and is an integer... I'm not sure why it says null because if i run the select query it shows the values. Also it has 2 rows, so i might not be sure if this only works for one

EDIT.

I'm copying files from a different record ID hence why i Need @IdNovo here to insert the new value in the foreign key ID column

Comment: You don't need VALUES here as it looks like you want SELECT @IdNovo

Comment: i need to insert the new ID. as the procedure name says, I'm copying files from a different ID

Comment: From what I'm seeing, calling the stored procedure will insert `@IdNovo` to  `hDocumentos.IdArtigo` and then will return the rows from the `SELECT` below the `INSERT`.

Comment: So calling it will return `(1 row(s) affected)` and then the results of the `SELECT` statement. The `INSERT` and the `SELECT` and completely separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `hDocumentos` looks like, but if  you want to insert `@IdNovo` *and* the rows from the `select` it would look something like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
    @IdArtigo int,
    @IdNovo int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO hDocumentos (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
    SELECT TipoDocumento, NomeDocumento,Dados, Extensao, Observacoes, @IdNovo
    FROM hDocumentos
    WHERE IdArtigo = @IdArtigo
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just looking for

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spInsertCopyDocumentos') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
    @IdArtigo int,
    @IdNovo int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- You can check the params for NULL here and raise an error
    INSERT INTO hDocumentos (IdArtigo) 
    SELECT @IdNovo 
    FROM hDocumentos
    WHERE IdArtigo = @IdArtigo
END
```

If you want to copy all the data then you need to specify the columns names as

```
INSERT INTO hDocumentos (IdArtigo, Col1, Col2, ..)
SELECT @IdNovo, ISNULL(Col1, <DefaultValue>), ISNULL(Col2, <DefaultValue>) ...
FROM hDocumentos
WHERE IdArtigo = @IdArtigo
```

and use `ISNULL()` to check for `NULL`s and replace it with a default value instead of `NULL` since your column `IS NOT NULL`.

For the error you get, that because you just specify `(IdArtigo)` column, that mean you will insert a row have `NULL`s except for `IdArtigo` column which you specify in the `INSERT` clause. So you are trying to insert a `NULL` value to `TipoDocumento` column, cause you did not specify which value to insert it to it.

Finally, your procedure should looks like:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spInsertCopyDocumentos') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertCopyDocumentos
    @IdArtigo int,
    @IdNovo int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- Optional if you need to check the paramaters if they NULL or not, that's up to you
    INSERT INTO hDocumentos (IdArtigo, 
                             TipoDocumento, 
                             NomeDocumento, 
                             Dados, 
                             Extensao, 
                             Observacoes) --The number of columns specified her must be the same in the select
    SELECT @IdNovo,
           ISNULL(TipoDocumento, <DefaultValue>), -- since it won't accept nulls
           --But since you are selecting from the same table it won't be a problem 
           NomeDocumento,
           Dados, 
           Extensao, 
           Observacoes 
    FROM hDocumentos
    WHERE IdArtigo = @IdArtigo
END
```

Comment: it still says cannot insert cause this column does not allow nulls, i don't get it if there is no null values

Answer (score 1):

ok i see how it works. I had to specify the column names on the insert  like a normal insert into query

```
INSERT INTO hDocumentos (TipoDocumento, NomeDocumento, Dados, Extensao, Observacoes,IdArtigo) 
SELECT TipoDocumento, NomeDocumento, Dados, Extensao, Observacoes, @IdNovo
FROM hDocumentos
WHERE IdArtigo = @IdArtigo
```